# Stop Older Phones From Installing My app

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm about to upload my app to the app store and I wanted to know: How would I stop individuals with iphone 5 and lower from installing my app? I don't want users who have anything lower than a iPhone 6 to be able to download it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not? Do you have something against people who prefer older tech?

Comment: Not really something against them but, I'm having trouble with the constraints for older apps. So, I'm just going to not allow older versions to use the app.

Comment: There is no way to block 4” phones. Which I’m guessing you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the architectures to arm64 only i.e. remove armv7s to stop iphone 5 and 5c (but not 5s). Note that this also removes the basic iPad 1-3 from downloading the app as well.

see: [apple device graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s5W.png)

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not support limiting app distribution to specific devices. The closest thing you can do to this is [setting your deployment target](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47) to a version of iOS that doesn't support the devices you want to avoid.

For example, if you set your deployment target to iOS 11.0, only those with a 5s or newer would be able to run your app.

Check out [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com) for a great visualization of which devices are supported by each version of iOS.